# Как реализовать обновление программы?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Имеется программа состоящая из exe, Word, ini и других файлов.

Как реализовать обновление определённых файлов программы на другом пк, а обновления отправлять из моего пк?

При наличии новой версии программа предложит обновить и если пользователь нажмет "обновить" то, программа обновится.

Программа сделана на ui с библиотекой Pyqt5.

Как реализовать данную программу??? Напишите кто может пример кода.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/377809

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я попросил пример кода, а не статью. Тем более в ней описывается логика по которой должна работать система обновления(а я и сам понимаю как она должна работать). И там для обновления используется сайт, а в моем случаи должен использоваться мой пк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой пк не имеет постоянного ip адреса, следовательно из сети интернет, он виден, но каждый раз с новыми параметрами. Так же на твоём пк должен быть поднят сервер. Так же скорость входящего подключения, должна быть выше твоей раз эдак в десять.

Comment: хорошо какие есть варианты кроме создания сайта?

Comment: более сложные, используя торрент. Так же можно реализовать это с помощью костылей в виде рассылке через почту, либо криво через сторнние файлообменники + редактируемый укорачитватель адреса.

Comment: можете привести пример с рассылкой по почте?

Comment: нет, данный метод ни когда не был особо популярен. Суть в отправке файлов либо ссылок на обновление по почте, реализуется либо через один общий емэйл, что ведёт к дыре в безопасности либо через кучу разных, что ведёт к проблемам "борьбы со спамом"

Comment: понял спасибо. Тогда покажите пример или киньте ссылку на статью с обновлением через сайт.

Comment: эммм могу только объяснить в кратце: программа переодически делает запрос на сайт получая в ответ строку новой версии, если версия новее то скачивает и запускает инсталятор. На сервере в простейшем виде лежит архив с номером версии.

Comment: спасибо. Когда сделаю сайт подробнее изучу данную тему.

Comment: для тренировок рекомендую программу openserver - поднимает сервер на пк

Comment: обязательно попробую